# am chart pie chart not reading json file data?

Tags: php, json, amcharts

when we pass static list of data like `[{category":"a","data:"3"},"category":"b","data":"1"}]`
then its working fine, but when we pass page url like `{"url": "abc.php","format": "json"}` in dataprovider section then chart not populate.

This is my code:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", { 
    "type": "pie", 
    "dataProvider":{ "
        url": "abc.php",
        "format": "json" }, 
    "labelRadius": -35, 
    "labelText": "[[percents]]%", 
    "titleField": "category", 
    "valueField": "column-1", 
    "allLabels": [], 
    "balloon": {}, 
    "legend": { 
        "enabled": true, 
        "align": "center", 
        "markerType": "circle" } 
    });
```

Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you paste your code, so we can see what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using amCharts with "static" data**

If you have "static"  data, use the `dataProvider` setting, like this:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "category": "a",
    "data": 3
  }, {
    "category": "b",
    "data": 1
  }],
  // ...
});
```

**Using amCharts with AJAX data**

If you want the data to be loaded using AJAX, one way is to make use of amCharts' Data Loader plugin.

Make sure to include it in your HTML:

```
<script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Leave out the `dataProvider` setting, and use `dataLoader` instead.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "abc.php",
    "format": "json"
  },
  // ...
});
```

Your `abc.php` file should return valid JSON, like this:

```
[{
  "category": "a",
  "data": 3
}, {
  "category": "b",
  "data": 1
}]
```

You can find a complete list of options for the Data Loader plugin here: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-data-loader-plugin/.

Comment: If i pass "dataProvider": [{"column-1":"10788","column-2":"17466"}] static, then its work for me, but when i pass "dataProvider": data dynamic data, then chart not populating.
Please help

Comment: Use "dataLoader" instead of "dataProvider" when loading data from a specific file.